# Роутинг на PHP. Проблема с подключением ресурсов сайта

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, роутинг

Я решил использовать у себя на сайте роутинг на PHP.

Проделав следующие действия:
Добавил вот такую структуру в **.htaccess**:

```html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Таким образом любой виртуальный адресс перенаправляется на **index.php** и я его там дальше обрабатываю как мне нужно.

- `site.com` - грузит мейновую страницу
- `site.com/reg` - грузит страницу reg
- `site.com/reg/login` - грузит страницу reg и передаёт в её параметр в виде строки со значением login
- `site.com/blog/art/123456` - грузит страницу blog и передаёт в её параметр в виде массива [art] => 123456
- `site.com/log/name/admin/pass/123` - грузит страницу log и передаёт массив

  ```
  [name] => admin
  [pass] => 123
  ```

В корне сайта находится лишь обработчик, страница ошибки и заглушки. Сам сайт находится в папке `/app`.

А теперь суть проблемы.
Почему сам сайт не может подключить ресурсы, его тоже перенаправляет на страницу ошибки? Проблема осталась со шрифтами, которые подключает бутстрап и частично js.

CSS и JS я подключил с помощью PHP. Но такой вариант не устраивает, можно ли как-то разрешить доступ сайту обращаться к своим же файлам, а пользовательские запросы обрабатывать?

Comment: Перед строкой `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]` добавьте строки `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` и `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` чтобы существующие папки и файлы не перенаправлялись в `index.php`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в конфигурации .htaccess

У Вас перенаправляются абсолютно все запросы, включая те, что должны ссылаться на существующие директории  и файлы. Соответственно, нужно ограничить это действие.

Рабочий пример конфига

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```